# Backtracking Equations

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-shape

[image: backtracking]

I have been trying create the code that will replicate the backtracking boxes. I've not been able to split the boxes without using two different tikz pictures. I want the arrows to go from middle of boxes, and I want enough space for the students to put the answers in the boxes. Also the text is upside in my picture and I can't put in equations using the $ sign because it's text.

My MWE is below

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzstyle{data}=[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,text centered]   
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (One) at (-2,0) [shape=rectangle,draw,  ] {$p$}; 
    \node (Two) at (2,0) [shape=rectangle,draw] {$2p$};
    \node (Three) at (6,0) [shape=rectangle,draw] {$2p - 5$};
        \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
    \draw [->,thick, red, postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily\myshift| x 2}}}]      (One) to [bend left=45] (Two);
    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
    \draw [->,thick, red, postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily\myshift| -5 }}}]      (Two) to [bend left=45] (Three);
\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
\draw [->,thick, red, postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily\myshift|  5 }}}]      (Three) to [bend left=45] (Two);

\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
\draw [->,thick, red, postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily\myshift| div 5  }}}]      (Two) to [bend left=45] (One);  
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Some remarks:

#### Split rectangle

- `\nodepart{two}` could have been omitted
- however, for using the `\strut` element I put them in
- `\strut` is a structure box with width 0
- in a `text` environment it simply keeps the height constant, as ...
- ... in a `node` height varies depending on text-content

#### Connections

- decoration is not needed here, making things easier to do
- using `to [bend left]` is just one way to bend lines
- to shift the anchor points of the arrows a little I used polar coordinates, see `% comments`
- there are several ways to place labels; here I used `node {}` inserted into the path
- their formattings `txt` and `txb` shift the labels away from the arrows

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% during development
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
                draw, %             show the rectangles
                minimum width=20mm% make large for a uniform width
                },
    arr/.style={->, red, >={Stealth}},
    txt/.style={black, yshift=+2.5mm},
    txb/.style={black, yshift=-2.5mm},
 ]
    % ~~~ text boxes ~~~~~~
    %     \strut is a LaTeX text element; effect: makes heights equal
    \node[box] (A) at (0,0) {\strut $p$                 \nodepart{two}\strut};
    \node[box] (B) at (3,0) {\strut $2 \times p$        \nodepart{two}\strut};
    \node[box] (C) at (6,0) {\strut $2 \times p - 5$    \nodepart{two}\strut};
    
    % ~~~ connectors ~~~~~~~
    %     anchors: (A.north) == (A.90); (A.south) == (A.270) 
    \draw [arr] (A.80) to [bend left] node[txt] {$\times 2$} (B.100);   
    \draw [arr] (B.80) to [bend left] node[txt] {$- 5$} (C.100);    
    
    \draw [arr] (C.260) to [bend left] node[txb] {$+ 5$} (B.280);   
    \draw [arr] (B.260) to [bend left] node[txb] {$\div 2$} (A.280);    
    
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Adding an `inner ysep=5mm` to the `box` style ...

```
    box/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
                draw, %             show the rectangles
                minimum width=20mm,% make large for a uniform width
                inner ysep=5mm
                },
```

results in

[image: ysep applied]

Comment: Nice, is there a line of code to make the rectangular boxes bigger, so the students can enter in the required information

Comment: You can use inner ysep, see ch. 17.2.3 in https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes. Just add it to the box style. E.g. inner ysep=5mm will make both nodeparts a bit bigger in y-direction. Or just make the box accept multilines and feed multiple lines to nodepart two.

Comment: I know it's not the done thing, but, thank you, I can now write my assessment for Monday because of you.  Knowing  the commands is one thing, I appreciate the link, but knowing how it all fits together is an entirely different issue. What you've wrote will be used by many secondary school mathematics teachers. By the way scale and resize box doesn't work for those wanting to try.

Answer (score 9):

If you need this more than once I recommend using the `chains` library which automatically places the nodes and can also connect them on-the-fly.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, shapes.multipart}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  save tikztonodes/.style={every to/.append style/.expanded={
    edge node={\pgfutil@unexpanded\expandafter{\tikz@tonodes}}}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  /utils/temp/.style n args={3}{
    backtracking equations/step #1/.style={edge label={$#2##1$}},
    backtracking equations/step' #1/.style={edge label={$#3##1$}}},
  /utils/temp/.list={++-, --+, *\times\div, :\div\times},
  every backtracking equations diagram/.style={
    start chain=going right, node distance=1em},
  backtracking equations/.cd,
  data/.style={
    rectangle split, draw, minimum width=4.6em,
    rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split horizontal=false},
  every conn/.style={auto=left, nodes={text=blue}, red, >=Latex, bend angle=30},
  arr >/.style 2 args={
    backtracking equations/every conn, ->, backtracking equations/step #1={#2},
    to path={[save tikztonodes] ([xshift=+0.1em]\tikztostart.north)
                  to[bend left] ([xshift=+-.1em]\tikztotarget.north)}},
  arr </.style 2 args={
    backtracking equations/every conn, <-, backtracking equations/step' #1={#2}, ',
    to path={[save tikztonodes] ([xshift=+0.1em]\tikztostart.south)
                 to[bend right] ([xshift=+-.1em]\tikztotarget.south)}}}
\newcommand*\tikzbackeq[2][]{%
  \tikz[every backtracking equations diagram,#1]
    \foreach \content/\step in {#2}
      \node[backtracking equations/data, on chain,
        join=by {backtracking equations/arr >/.expand once=\step},
        join=by {backtracking equations/arr </.expand once=\step}]
        {\strut$\content$ \nodepart{two} \strut};}
\begin{document}
\tikzbackeq{p, 2p/*2, 2p-5/-5}

\tikzbackeq{p, p+3/+3, \frac{p+3}{2}/:2, \pi\frac{p+3}{2}/*\pi}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, is there a line of code to make the rectangular boxes bigger, so the students can enter in the required information

Comment: @Jon Bigger in what direction? The `minimum width` in the `data` style changes the width. For changing the height, you can replace the second `\strut` with something like `\rule{0pt}{2em}`.

Answer (score 6):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and Tikz to draw the arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{O}{w{c}{1cm}}

\[\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\begin{NiceArray}{OcOcO}
\Block[hvlines]{2-1}{}p && \Block[hvlines]{2-1}{}2p && \Block[hvlines]{2-1}{} 2p-5 \\
\\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [->, draw=red, >=Latex, bend left]
    \draw (1-|1.5) to node [auto] { $\times 2$ } (1-|3.5) ; 
    \draw (1-|3.5) to node [auto] { $-5$ } (1-|5.5) ; 
    \draw (3-|5.5) to node [auto] { $+5$ } (3-|3.5) ; 
    \draw (3-|3.5) to node [auto] { $\div 2$ } (3-|1.5) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]